# Remove and Restore datatables pagination click functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, pagination

I have a datatables instance on a web page that has full numbers pagination.  This includes First,Previous,Next and Last buttons plus the individual numbered buttons.

Each row in the table has an 'Edit' link. When I click it, I want to disable the pagination from working. When I click a 'Cancel' button, I want to restore the pagination functionality.  I can do the first part easy enough, but I cannot restore the pagination click functionality. Here's my code:

```
function ghostPage(state)
{
    // In this method, 'state' will be either true or false
    // If it's true, remove the click handler
    // If it's false, restore the click handler

    if(state)
    {
        $('#displayTable_paginate').find('a').each(function(e){
            $(this).off('click');
        })
    }
    else
    {
        $('#displayTable_paginate').find('a').each(function(){
            $(this).on('click');
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this if you want to save the click handler and restore it later.

```
function saveClickHander(){
    var $this;
    $('#displayTable_paginate').find('a').each(function(e){
        $this = $(this);
        $this.data().originalClick = $this.data("events")['click'][0].handler;
    }) 

}

function ghostPage(state)
{
    // In this method, 'state' will be either true or false
    // If it's true, remove the click handler
    // If it's false, restore the click handler

    if(state)
    {
        $('#displayTable_paginate').find('a').each(function(e){
            $(this).off('click');
        })
    }
    else
    {
        var $this;
        $('#displayTable_paginate').find('a').each(function(){
            $this = $(this);
            $this.on('click', $this.data().originalClick);
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how that works.  I tried it without effect though.

Comment: I should say that, I am fine with some other way to prevent the click event from working.  I've tried disabling the parent divs without success.  I can hide the whole div of buttons, but that is very clunky.  It's weird; it seems I can do everything else I want with these divs except toggle the clicks on and off.

Comment: Originally, the click handler function is bound to the element's click listener. $(this).off('click') is just setting the handler reference to null. You want to store the reference somewhere before unbinding so that you can restore it later. I am not sure why it is not working for you. It might be because you used "div.onclick=funciton(){...}".  It seems that disabling the element is a better way to do, but I don't think there is a "disable" function in JQuery. An alternative  can be hiding the buttons and showing the non-responsive buttons with the same style, though it is sort of ugly..

Comment: I will say check if $('#displayTable_paginate').find('a').first().data("events")['click'][0].handler is null

Comment: No, it is not null until after I remove the click handler.  In the context of my code, how ( and where ) do I call the 'saveClickHandler()' function you provided?

Comment: I found a solution that works with IE(10), Chrome and Firefox:

if(state)
 { 
  $('#displayTable_paginate').css({'pointer-events':'none','cursor':'default'});  
 }
 else
 {
   $('#displayTable_paginate').css({'pointer-events':'auto','cursor':'pointer'});  
 }

Comment: I am glad you find the solution! I think it is the best way of disabling the button. For saveClickHandler(), you can call it any where before $('#displayTable_paginate').find('a').each(function(e){
            $(this).off('click');
        }) is excuted.